# Appropriate book for propositional logic

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, propositional-calculus, book-recommendation

I am not looking for a good book but an appropriate book that is suitable for my logic course. Currently the professor only offers lectures. (Not sure why, perhaps there is no universal approach to logic, so no suitable book?) Ideally, the book contains question similar to the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51173/question-about-maximally-consistent-sets-in-logic). Any suggestions would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what's appropriate for your course without more details.  "Propositional and Predicate Calculus: A Model of Argument" by Derek Goldrei ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/propositional-and-predicate-calculus-a-model-of-argument/oclc/638920222?referer=di&ht=edition)) may be helpful: it has exercises with solutions and is designed for independent study.